# Excel macro, comma separated cell to column

Tags: excel

How can I write an Excel macro which would transform one cell with comma-separated values into multiple columns?

### Input:

[image]

### Wanted result:

[image]

Comment: I have mbedded the images, put the request into words, fixed the tags. Now, one question remains: has the OP tried anything?

Comment: Range.TextToColumns should do the trick (with the right settings of course)